# Python2でunicode型をISO-8859-1に変換したい

Tags: python

Python2のエンコーディングについてよくわからないので教えて下さい。

```
s = '象'.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

上のコードのsを`u'象'`(utf-8)から作り出したいのですがどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: `utf-8` に encode してから decode するとか。`u'象'.encode('utf-8').decode('ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: その方法でできました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utf-8 に encode してから decode する例です。

```
u'象'.encode('utf-8').decode('ISO-8859-1')
```